# Submodules in Lua

Tags: lua

I don't understand how work with sub modules in Lua.

For example, let there be a module "Example" and "SubExample". There are realizations:

```
"Example":
--------------
local Example={};

function Example.launch(f)
  local sbEx = require('Module:SubExample')
  sbEx(f.args[1])
end

return Example
--------------
"SubExample":
--------------
 return function (argument)
   return argument
 end   
--------------
```

It must return what is transferred.

Okay. But how calling functions in "Example" from "SubExample" if "SubExample" will be in this style:

```
local SubExample={};

function SubExample.retArgument(f)
  return f
end

return SubExample
```

So, how call in "Example" function retArgument from SubExample?

Comment: `sbEx.retArgument(f.args[1])`